# How to loop a specific file in HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I would like to know if it's possible to loop only a specific files like video/mp4? In the folder I have also multiple files and sub-foldes and the html load every elements.

```
{% for file in video_files %}
<video controls width="250" height="250">
<source src={{ url_for('static', filename=file) }} type="video/mp4">
</video>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the code.

Python with Flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sys

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

import os

path = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    files = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            files.append(file)
    video_files = files
    return render_template('index.html', video_files=video_files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Is this Twig? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually it's Flask and it's complicated to manage the static folder. I'm kind of new with html and front end part.

Comment: You should probably post the code where you populate `video_files`

Comment: @ramblex I did, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: So is it `audio_files` or `video_files`? Your python code is confusing about that. Avoid that confusion and just pass `files` to `render_template`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I correct the code, i'm modify the wrong part. Thanks for modify my post <3 thanks for helping me guys <3

Comment: Did you try `for file in [f for f in video_files if f[-3:] == 'mp4']` ?

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx I'm trying to implement this part :) I will reply asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solve the problem: Thanks xxMrPHDxx give a good feedback.

P.s thanks for the (-1) really helpful for people and for the community!

```
def index():
    files = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if file.find('mp4') > -1:
                files.append(file)
    video_files = files
    return render_template('index.html', video_files=video_files)
```